Apple Watch Getting 561015905 while trying to initiate recording when the app is in background
I'm trying to start and stop recording when my app is in background periodically. I implemented it using Timer and DispatchQueue. However whenever I am trying to initiate the recording I get this error. This issue does not exist in foreground.
Here is the current state of my app and configuration.
I have added "Background Modes" capability in the Signing & Capability and I also checked Audio and Self Care. Here is my Info.plist:
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
    </array>
    <key>WKBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>self-care</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

I also used the AVAudioSession with .record category and activated it. Here is the code snippet:
func startPeriodicMonitoring() {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.record, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers])
            try session.setActive(true, options: [])
            print("Session Activated")
            print(session)
            // Start recording.
            measurementTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: measurementInterval, repeats: true) { _ in
                self.startMonitoring()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.recordingDuration) {
                    self.stopMonitoring()
                }
            }
            measurementTimer?.fire()  // Start immediately
        } catch let error {
            print("Unable to set up the audio session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

And I get The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error 561015905.)
Any thoughts on this?

The error code 561015905 is AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotStartPlaying, which is odd as I would have expected AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotStartRecording (561145187) for your case, but the fact is that you cannot start audio input or output in the background. The background audio entitlement only allows continuing audio IO that you already started in the background.
So you could either start recording from the foreground and never stop it, or find other hook (apart from a timer) from where you can start audio IO, e.g. if you were on iOS you could do it at the end of an audio interruption or some CoreBlueTooth callbacks IIRC.

Thank you for your answer. At first I was getting 561145187 but after I added the mixWithOthers  option in the setCategory the error changed to 561015905. For the hooks that you mentioned since I am using watchOS do you have any suggestion?

At first I started the audio in the foreground and I didn't stop it in the background and it was working. However, due to the high power consumption I decided to change the method to start and stop recording only for some periods. My ultimate goal is to do some analysis on the environment noise and I do not need the microphone to be open at all times.
